# Showing information on Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I'm fairly new to working with Google Maps API. When embedding a map you get the place and a white box in the top right hand corner with a little information on the place. However I want to use the JavaScript API and want to know is there anyway to replicate this with the JavaScript API and not the iframe embed.

Thanks.

Comment: you can try to use infoWindow https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#InfoWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically to display the information you would need to use the infoWindow, yes. You can attach an infoWindow to either a marker or directly to map co-ordinates. In depth documentation about infoWindow and detailed references can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows).